# jQuery creating unwanted DIV..net MVC

Tags: jquery, .net, model-view-controller

I have an issue with jQuery, i recently came across a problem.

It creates an extra div. When using .html(data) from an ajax call. I am probably missing something. But this is causing me abit of a headache, since i cannot properly hide the Div, since .hide() and .show() only triggers on the first one.

Anyone here who could help me solve this? In advance, thank you

```
<div id="DropDown">
    <div id="AddCustomer">
        <div id="AddCustomer">
            <select id="CustomerToAdd" name="GetAllSupplier">
             ...
            </select>
            <a class=""></a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Ajax:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: urlGetSupplier,
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#AddCustomer").html(data);
        }
    });
```

Parentview:

```
<div id="DropDown">
            @Html.Partial("_SupplierList", new CustomerModels())
        </div>
```

Partialview:

```
<div id="AddCustomer">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.GetSupplier, new SelectList(Model.GetSupplier, "ID", "Name"), new { @id = "CustomerToAdd" })
    <a class="AddCustomerBtn">Add</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Sounds like you should be doing `$("#DropDown").replaceWith(data)`, but I'm not 100% sure that I understand your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ofcourse it will because that's how you designed it. You are adding the partial view content which is wrapped under `<div id="AddCustomer">` to already existing `<div id="AddCustomer">`.

Change your ajax success function to use parent div instead of self containing div:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: urlGetSupplier,
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#DropDown").html(data);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. Makes sense, guess i just stared at it for way to long. Seeing as im quite new to .net mvc this was abit tricky for me :)